# Twitter Bootstrap: white space on left and right side in smaller screen widths?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have markup similar to this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Obviously, I want the `.container-fluid` to span the entire width of the screen. However, in smaller screen widths, it doesn't seem to do that. There appears a space on both sides of the screen, thus reducing the amount of screen real estate and affecting the overall look and feel I'm trying to achieve.

Is there a way to get rid of this space? I want `.container-fluid` to span the entire width of the screen regardless of the screen width.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In bootstrap-responsive.css, the body gets a 20px padding on the left and right at smaller windows sizes.  If you don't want that at all, remove it from your version. It's at line 803 and looks like this:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  /*body { These are the lines you want to remove
    padding-right: 20px; 
    padding-left: 20px;
  }*/
```

If you just want to remove the white space on a certain element or class, add these margins to it:

```
 margin-left:-20px;
 margin-right:-20px;
```

Comment: Wouldn't it just be 0px and not -20px?

Comment: No, since the padding is on the body.  If you set the padding:0px on the body, that would work (but you might as well remove it from the css at that point).  Since it's a div in the padded body, adding the negative margins makes it go flush with the window size for only that one element.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem using **Bootstrap 3.0**. Solved it for small screens by putting:

```
.container {
     padding-right: 0; /*15px in bootstrap.css*/
     padding-left: 0;  /*idem*/
     margin-right: auto;
     margin-left: auto;
}
```

in my own stylesheet.

Comment: perfect, just what i was looking for

Comment: This makes a scroll bar appear though, any ideas why?

Comment: Thanks so much for this ! I was searching for ages to get the bars removed.

Comment: This works in BS4. Since I'm using _container-fluid_, I added the _-fluid_ .

Answer (score 3):

Simply

```
.container-fluid {
     padding:0;
}
```

If scroll bar appears its due to border box, there must be

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

in relevant class to make scroll bar disappear

Answer (score 2):

Just add class 'p-0' beside 'container-fluid' class because in bootstrap padding:0 is already defined.

```
<div class="container-fluid p-0">Content goes here</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The two white margins are created by the classes `content` and `body-content`. If you are using these classes in any outer div, try removing these classes from them to remove the blank margins on either side of the page.

Answer (score 0):

White space are caused by padding in bootstrap class. 
You can overwrite the bootstrap class by adding an id

```
<div id="remove-padding" class="container-fluid">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the .css

```
#remove-padding {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem tried the above solutions but none worked for me.

This worked for me.

```
  html{
    width: fit-content;
  }
```