# Large right margin when browser is shrunk to mobile size on Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I apologize for lack of code examples in this question but I'm not even sure what to put. If you visit this page:

http://www.theplaybook.co

You'll notice that if you resize the browser window to a mobile device size a large white margin appears on the right hand side of the page.

I can't seem to figure out why this is happening. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its coming from this padding:

```
 @media (max-width: 767px){
    body {
        padding-right: 20px;
        padding-left: 20px;
    }
 }
```

Line: 803 from this file > http://theplaybook.co/wp-content/themes/playbook/css/bootstrap-responsive.css?ver=3.5.2

**In response to your comment:** (*try this*)

```
 @media (max-width: 767px){
    .navbar {
       padding:0 20px;
    } 
 }
```

Comment: That does get rid of the 20px padding. Thank you : )

Comment: Still a problem though. The Playbook logo in the header now disappears partially off the screen as well as the menu button. Also, there's still a large white margin on the right hand side. Any ideas?

Comment: See my edit.. It looks like you just need to handle the navbar padding differently for that media size.

Comment: What do you see happening? The logo and menu don't seem to be cut off anymore? Are you expecting something else?

Comment: Yeah, I that's working but the margin on the right is still there. If you shrink your browser window to mobile size you'll still see a white margin on right hand side.

Comment: part of that is coming from your social media section... try `.social {overflow:hidden;}`

Comment: Another solution.. (maybe not the best) would be to do. `body{overflow-x:hidden;}`

Comment: Thanks, Kris. That was a huge part of the problem. There's still a small 20px padding issue but I think I can figure that out. Thanks for taking the time to help me with this. Much appreciated : )

Answer (score 1):

In bootstrap-responsive.css, the body gets a 20px padding on the left and right at smaller windows sizes.  If you don't want that at all, remove it from your version. It's at line 803 and looks like this:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  /*body { These are the lines you want to remove
    padding-right: 20px; 
    padding-left: 20px;
  }*/
```

If you just want to remove the white space on a certain element or class, add these margins to it:

```
 margin-left:-20px;
 margin-right:-20px;
```

Taken from my answer at [Twitter Bootstrap: white space on left and right side in smaller screen widths?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17560818/twitter-bootstrap-white-space-on-left-and-right-side-in-smaller-screen-widths/17560929#17560929)