# Navbar created with bootstraps has white space on left and right

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to customize my navbar for a Ruby on Rails application, however, the left and right sides of it are not following the colors so it looks like the image below.

[image]

Notice the white spaces to the left and right. I got the inner-most part to change color by changing the `.container` background color in my `style.css`.

```
/*********
Navbar Styles
**********/

.navbar-static-top .container {
  background-color: #3f51b5;
}
```

Though the sides don't change.

Selecting my navbar and seeing what the `.container` div is covering, it looks like it should be the entire navbar as per the picture below.

[image]

So, I would think I am changing the background of the correct element. I read some things how bootstraps adds [unecessary padding to the right and left.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17560818/twitter-bootstrap-white-space-on-left-and-right-side-in-smaller-screen-widths) So I tried implementing those overrides in my `style.css` file, but it also did not work.

So I'm at a lost for what's going on, my guess is somewhere Rails or Bootstraps or maybe the Devise gem for user authentication somehow, is generating this weird padding on the sides when I don't want it. Though I don't know. I was using some like, template HTML/CSS files at the start but I removed all them. The only style sheets in my Assets folder are mine, application.scss, and users.scss but users.scss has nothing in it.

Any help would be appreciated thanks in advance.

style.css

```
/*********
Navbar Styles
**********/

.navbar-static-top .container {
  background-color: #3f51b5;
  padding-right: 0; /*15px in bootstrap.css*/
  padding-left: 0;  /*idem*/
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  border-color: #3f51b5;
}

/**********
Devise Alert styles
***********/
.alert-box {
  color:#555;
  border-radius:10px;
  font-family:Tahoma,Geneva,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:11px;
  padding:10px 10px 10px 36px;
  margin:10px;
  span {
    font-weight:bold;
    text-transform:uppercase;
  }
}
.danger {
    background:#ffecec url('images/error.png') no-repeat 10px 50%;
    border:1px solid #f5aca6;
}
.success {
    background:#e9ffd9 url('images/success.png') no-repeat 10px 50%;
    border:1px solid #a6ca8a;
}
.warning {
    background:#fff8c4 url('images/warning.png') no-repeat 10px 50%;
    border:1px solid #f2c779;
}
.notice {
    background:#e3f7fc url('images/notice.png') no-repeat 10px 50%;
    border:1px solid #8ed9f6;
}
```

application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Shiplist</title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <%= link_to 'SHIP LIST', root_path, class: "navbar-brand"%>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <% if user_signed_in?%>
                <li><%= link_to 'post ad', new_listing_path %></li>
                <li><%= link_to 'log out', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %></li>
                <% else %>
                <li><%= link_to 'sign up', new_user_registration_path %></li>
                <li><%= link_to 'log in', new_user_session_path %></li>
                <% end %>
            </ul>
        </div>
</nav>
<body>
<%= render 'layouts/messages' %>
<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should put background color in `navbar` class instead of container, you have `navbar-default` class with background `#f8f8f8` try to overwrite that or  add new class inside navbar.

Comment: Adding another class in there worked, thank you. I did try actually changing the navbar-default color but it didn't work. Not sure why that works though, but thanks!

Comment: Please add a [mcve]

Comment: You may post your solution as an answer and accept it later, unless a better answer makes its way in the meantime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try overwriting the `navbar-default` on your own style.css.

```css
.navbar-default{
  background-color: /*your color here*/  !important;
}
```

or if you want to get rid of the unnecessary white spaces, remove the `class="container"`then add `padding: 0 1% /*example*/` to `.navbar-default`.

Comment: That worked as well, kind of like that better instead of adding another class as talked about in the comments. Thank you.